# Carousel page image move

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

It is a little hard to describe use language, so please take a look at this site [Example](http://www.architizer.com/projects/carousel/)

While you are scrolling the page, you could see that the Carousel image on top of the page is move slower than the rest of the page. That is, the image and the rest of the page are not moving at the same speed while you scrolling.

I am working on a very simple Carousel page (using bootstrap), and would like to implement such an effect as well. 
Could someone please point me how to implement it?

Thank you

Comment: That effect is called Parallax. Try checking this out: http://stephband.info/jparallax/